# Is there an elegant way to upgrade jQuery slowly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, version-control, jquery-plugins

We are wanting to upgrade from one version of jQuery to another.  We use various online plug-in's and have written many of our own.  The challenge now comes in the form of trying to SLOWLY MIGRATE all your scripted objects SLOWLY without a complete re-write.  I have an idea on HOW to handle this:

**BUT I HAVE QUESTIONS:**

1. Is the idea below even a good idea?
2. Can I (directly) tell each jQuery object where dependencies live?
3. If this is a bad idea...how do YOU handle it?
4. Do I simply re-write EVERY object that happens to break upon upgrading? (sux!)

**EXPLAINING THE ISSUE:**
If all your plug-in's live ONLY within the scope of a single page, then different versions are easily addressed: simply do your file-includes at the page level instead of the master-page level (duh!).  However, objects that live in the master-page or in user-controls are a bit tougher...as they need specific versions to run correctly.

**HERE'S MY IDEA:**
The definition of a plug-in starts with an anonymous function.

```
(function ($){<!- code goes here -->})(jQuery);
```

All of the dependencies I've seen use this as a starting point.

EXAMPLES: 
jQuery dependencies include plug-ins like: ui.widget, ui.position, ui.core, etc.

So what if I reference each version of jQuery (and its dependencies) using a JavaScript object and pass THAT OBJECT INTO the various in-house and online plug-ins?

**THE OBJECT REFERENCES MIGHT GO LIKE THIS:**

```
var jQueryVersion1_3_2 = function(){<!- paste the files contents here-->};
var jQueryVersion1_4_4 = function(){<!- paste the files contents here-->};
```

**THE PLUG-INS:**
My in-house and online plug-ins could still be included as (normal) file-links, but with the following changes

GO FROM THIS:

```
// Plug-in X
(function ($){<!- its untouched code -->})(jQuery);
// Plug-in Y
(function ($){<!- its untouched code -->})(jQuery);
// Plug-in Z
(function ($){<!- its untouched code -->})(jQuery);
```

...versioning sucks here!

TO THIS...

```
// Plug-in X
(function ($){<!- its untouched code -->})(jQueryVersion1_3_2);
// Plug-in Y
(function ($){<!- its untouched code -->})(jQueryVersion1_3_2);
// Plug-in Z
(function ($){<!- its untouched code -->})(jQueryVersion1_4_4);
```

...now we can upgrade our objects SLOWLY.

**THE ONLY ISSUE I SEE:**
The challenge becomes the plug-in dependencies (between versions). In a test upgrade the following began to break across various plug-ins, things like:

- ui.widget, ui.position, ui.core, etc. (all broke upon upgrading).

**THE ONLY ANSWER I SEE IS:**
Wrapping jQuery and all the various references into a single function and saving THAT into the variable above.  Then pass THAT intermediary object into each plug-in AS jQuery.

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi...you're my only hope!

Comment: What's the reason for that? Do you think some of your plugins would stop working after the upgrade? (Just curious... In my experience moving to a newer version of jQuery has always been painless)

Comment: Are you using that many deprecated functions? You can always check out `http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2` (changing 1.3.2 with the version in question) and look at what may need to be changed. otherwise, loading each library and `var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict()` may be your best bet (though arguably a lot of overhead).

Comment: Remember, we don't want to have to re-write every plug-in.  We want to touch only a few at-a-time.  We have many plug-ins: some developed in-house and others from online sources. And yes...objects are failing once upgraded due to being deprecated etc.  But that's not the question. I already know how to painfully guess-and-test...I'm looking for something more elegant.

Comment: @Robalot: Elegent is probably changing the scope of each plugin, then creating a handler that can be passed a jQuery version which it goes and fetches said version, and performs a find/replace within the file (save the trouble loading each one and calling `.noConflict`) looking for `jQuery` and making it `jQuery_<version>`. Something like `<script src="jQuery.ashx?ver=1.3.2">` which returns `jQuery_1_3_2`, which then is references with `(function($){...})(jQuery_1_3_2);`

Comment: @Brad:  I sincerely appreciate the feedback.  Maybe I don't understand...how is that different from my idea above?

Comment: @Robalot: It's not, in the regard of having to go through the plugins and change what they reference for the "base jQuery object", however it makes loading multiple/various versions of jQuery (essentially) atop each other a tad bit easier. otherwise you're always calling "import script, call no conflict", rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Using $.noConflict to globally create all your versions

```
<script src="jquery 1.x" />
<script> 
    var jQuery_1_x = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
...
```

Then wrap every jQuery plugin, internal or 3rd party in closures like:

```
(function(jQuery, $) {

    ... // code

}(jQuery_1_x, jQuery_1_x));
```

The only thing that can break with this method is 3rd party code that uses `var foo` outside of any functions to create global objects. You need look for any global functions/objects/methods and hoist them manually using

`window.foo = ...`

Thankfully creating global functions/objects/methods is considered bad form by that method anyway so there shouldn't be too many of those.

Comment: QUESTION: Using noConflict(true) removes all jQuery variables from the global scope...so how does it help you when you want to use 2 variables to hold differing versions of jQuery?  - Thanks

Comment: Here is what noConflict does: window.$ = _$; if (deep) window.jQuery = _jQuery; return jQuery;  All I see is that it writes the jQuery object to a global variable in the window (instead of the $)...so I must be missing something. -Thanks

Comment: @Robalot when a version of jQuery loads it caches the variables in `$` and `jQuery` currently into `_S` and `_jQuery`. The first load of jQuery will cache `undefined`. What this does is set's the `undefined` values backs and returns a reference to `$`. So it removes jQuery from global scope and returns jQuery.